# Why is token is undefined on client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, next.js, jwt

I make an ecommerce site with nextjs and mongoose using a jwt token in a cookie, going client side in the console, the "application" parameter we can see the cookie which is stored with the name OursiteJWT and it has the value the token :

[image]

But after several tests we notice that when I retrieve the token it is undefined
pages/orders.js :

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import cookie from "cookie";

function Orders() {
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchOrders() {
      try {
        // Récupère le secret depuis l'API
        const secretRes = await axios.get("/api/secret");
        const secret = secretRes.data.secret;
        console.log(secret);
        // Récupère le token JWT depuis les cookies
        const cookies = cookie.parse(document.cookie);
        const token = cookies.OursiteJWT;
        console.log(token);
        // Si le token n'est pas présent, redirige vers la page de login
        if (!token) {
          console.log("pas de token")
          return;
        }

        // Vérifie le token JWT
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, secret);
        const userId = decoded._id;

        // Récupère les commandes de l'utilisateur depuis l'API
        const ordersRes = await axios.get(`/api/orders?user_id=${userId}`);
        const orders = ordersRes.data;

        setOrders(orders);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }

    fetchOrders();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {orders.map((order) => (
        <div key={order._id}>
          <h2>Commande {order._id}</h2>
          <p>Utilisateur: {order.name}</p>
          <p>Adresse: {order.address}</p>
          <p>Ville: {order.city}</p>
          <p>Produits:</p>
          <ul>
            {order.products.map((product) => (
              <li key={product._id}>{product.name}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Orders;
```

In the console I have "token not found" and the token value is undefined, the secret is correct.

This is how I stored the token :

api/login.js :

```js
import {initMongoose} from "../../lib/mongoose";
import User from '../../models/User';
import { sign } from "jsonwebtoken";
import { serialize } from "cookie";



initMongoose()
const secret = process.env.SECRET;

export default async function handler(req,res){
  
  const {email,password}=req.body;
  const user = await User.findOne({email,password});
  
  if(!user){
    res.status(401).json({message: "Impossible de trouver un utilisateur"});
    return;
  }
  else{
    
    const token = sign(
      {
        exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // 30 days
        email: email,
        _id: user._id,
      },
      secret
    );
    const serialised = serialize("OursiteJWT", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
      sameSite: "strict",
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
      path: "/",
    });
    
    res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", serialised);
    res.status(200).json({message :"Success!"});
    
    
  }

}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but how are you able to look up a user BY PASSWORD? Does this mean that you store passwords in plaintext or hashes without a salt?!

Comment: Ah yes you are right I do it by password too @ThiefMaster 
I will take care of user security after fixing this token error

Comment: you re still testing in local developement or already deploy ?

Comment: local @ShueiYang

Comment: You can't access httponly cookie using client-side javascript

Comment: I have to make an http request with the get method to my server side? @Konrad

Comment: No he mean you can't read the cookie en client side when httpOnly is set to true, even if you can see it. I though in local with http you can still read it, but no i guess

Comment: Anyway is not good practice to check the jwt in the cookie on the frontend, this should be done at the backend like with passport jwt strategy, since when you deploy, it's recommand to set httpOnly to true but give a try and set it to false on this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are unable to retrieve it is because you are setting       `httpOnly: true` on the cookie.

Using the HttpOnly flag when generating a cookie helps mitigate the risk of client side script accessing the protected cookie (if the browser supports it).

> A cookie with the HttpOnly attribute is inaccessible to the JavaScript
> `Document.cookie` API; it's only sent to the server. For example,
> cookies that persist in server-side sessions don't need to be
> available to JavaScript and should have the HttpOnly attribute. This
> precaution helps mitigate cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies